Godot cutting off bottom of geometry with webexport
So I've been working on a small project to be hosted on a subdomain so people can access it for a short demo. When I web export and send to the website, there is a weird bug that shows up when it loads. When you look at specific angles, the first couple inches of everything but the ground just disappears, as if it's being culled. Are there any settings I can change or anything I'm doing wrong? If you want to take a look at an example, the current build is hosted here
